# Calling Javascript within AppleScript to logout of Facebook Missing Value

Tags: javascript, facebook, applescript, getelementbyid

I'm writing an Applescript utility to login to Facebook, do some simple tasks and then logout. I have everything working except logging out. I want to use Safari and most reliable method recommended has been to call Javascript versus using System Events. I'm open to either way as long as I can log out the user. The logout action is a menulist item which I attempt to locate, however I get "missing value" using this code. You help is greatly appreciated!

```
tell application "Safari"
if not (exists document 1) then reopen
tell document 1
    set URL to "https://www.facebook.com"
    delay 3
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('email').value='email-address';
document.getElementById('pass').value='password-value';
document.getElementById('loginbutton').click();
document.getElementById('persist_box').value='0';"
end tell

-- working code --
-- working code

-- Need to logout of this account

tell document 1
    set URL to "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php"
    delay 3
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('logout_form').childNodes[0].click();"
end tell
end tell

-- from the Facebook page View Code
-- role="menuitem"><form id="logout_form" method="post" action="https://www.facebook.com/logout.php"    
onsubmit="return
```

Answer (score 0):

Found help elsewhere. This worked!

```
tell application "Safari"
tell document 1
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('logout_form').submit()"
end tell
end tell
```